# Google maps for android polyline issue

Tags: android, gps

I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 for my android application. I want to draw a polyline on it. It is working but it connects the start and the end points as well as a loop. How can fix this issue. Please refer the image. Sorry, I have covered all the location names because of the privacy issues on the image.
[image]

Following is my code. path is a LatLng type ArrayList and it contains all the points taken from the Google direction service.

```
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();;
        // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
        lineOptions.addAll(path);
        lineOptions.width(2);
        lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        lineOptions.geodesic(false);

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
```

Followings are a set of location I used.

```
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8509 lng:79.98403
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85083 lng:79.98397
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85061 lng:79.98386
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85031 lng:79.98372
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84994 lng:79.98348
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84983 lng:79.98338
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84972 lng:79.98328
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8496 lng:79.98324
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84946 lng:79.98327
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84925 lng:79.98332
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84908 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84894 lng:79.98357
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84885 lng:79.98368
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84875 lng:79.98378
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8487 lng:79.9839
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84864 lng:79.98404
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.648: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84857 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84754 lng:79.98453
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84606 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84593 lng:79.98412
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84591 lng:79.98405
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84587 lng:79.98385
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84582 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.658: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84575 lng:79.98292
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8509 lng:79.98403
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85083 lng:79.98397
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85061 lng:79.98386
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85031 lng:79.98372
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84994 lng:79.98348
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84983 lng:79.98338
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84972 lng:79.98328
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8496 lng:79.98324
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84946 lng:79.98327
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84925 lng:79.98332
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84908 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84894 lng:79.98357
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84885 lng:79.98368
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84875 lng:79.98378
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8487 lng:79.9839
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84864 lng:79.98404
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84857 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84754 lng:79.98453
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84606 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84593 lng:79.98412
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84591 lng:79.98405
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84587 lng:79.98385
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84582 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84575 lng:79.98292
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8509 lng:79.98403
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85083 lng:79.98397
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85061 lng:79.98386
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85031 lng:79.98372
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84994 lng:79.98348
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84983 lng:79.98338
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84972 lng:79.98328
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8496 lng:79.98324
10-13 23:18:42.678: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84946 lng:79.98327
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84925 lng:79.98332
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84908 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84894 lng:79.98357
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84885 lng:79.98368
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84875 lng:79.98378
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8487 lng:79.9839
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84864 lng:79.98404
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84857 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84754 lng:79.98453
10-13 23:18:42.688: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84606 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84593 lng:79.98412
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84591 lng:79.98405
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84587 lng:79.98385
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84582 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84575 lng:79.98292
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8509 lng:79.98403
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85083 lng:79.98397
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85061 lng:79.98386
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.85031 lng:79.98372
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84994 lng:79.98348
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84983 lng:79.98338
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84972 lng:79.98328
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8496 lng:79.98324
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84946 lng:79.98327
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84925 lng:79.98332
10-13 23:18:42.698: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84908 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84894 lng:79.98357
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84885 lng:79.98368
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84875 lng:79.98378
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8487 lng:79.9839
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84864 lng:79.98404
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.708: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8486 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84857 lng:79.98436
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84754 lng:79.98453
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84606 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84605 lng:79.98475
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84593 lng:79.98412
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84591 lng:79.98405
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84587 lng:79.98385
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84582 lng:79.98344
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84573 lng:79.98293
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.84575 lng:79.98292
10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272
```

Comment: ok well its obviously the points you are giving it and thats all we can say since you show no code

Answer (score 1):

Some of the points are "duplicated".... i mean, looking at your points list for example:
10-13 23:18:42.668: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272

... [93 more points]...

10-13 23:18:42.718: I/System.out(20202): Lat:6.8469 lng:79.98272

There are 93 points between one and the other, this makes the route to come back to this point.
The path is drawn 'continuously', so the order of your points is important.
you should double check the points (maybe a KMZ/KML on google earth could help)

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. It works after removing the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

V.1
Could you post how you draw your line?

V.2
Could you also post the data from your path, cause the problem is probably that the start and end point is next to each other in that list.

V.3
Try to reverse your list of data. 
Are you only drawing this once, or in some kind of loop?

V.4 You have the same data more than one time 
Look at these sections:

```
path.add(new LatLng(6.84605,79.98475));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84593,79.98412));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84591,79.98405));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84587,79.98385));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84582,79.98344));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84575,79.98292));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8469,79.98272));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8509,79.98403));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85083,79.98397));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85061,79.98386));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85031,79.98372));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84994,79.98348));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84983,79.98338));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84972,79.98328));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8496,79.98324));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84946,79.98327));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84925,79.98332));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84908,79.98344));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84894,79.98357));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84885,79.98368));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84875,79.98378));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8487,79.9839));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84864,79.98404));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8486,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8486,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84857,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84754,79.98453));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84606,79.98475));



    path.add(new LatLng(6.84605,79.98475));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84605,79.98475));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84593,79.98412));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84591,79.98405));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84587,79.98385));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84582,79.98344));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84575,79.98292));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8469,79.98272));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8509,79.98403));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85083,79.98397));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85061,79.98386));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.85031,79.98372));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84994,79.98348));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84983,79.98338));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84972,79.98328));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8496,79.98324));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84946,79.98327));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84925,79.98332));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84908,79.98344));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84894,79.98357));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84885,79.98368));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84875,79.98378));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8487,79.9839));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84864,79.98404));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8486,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8486,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84857,79.98436));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84754,79.98453));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84606,79.98475));



    path.add(new LatLng(6.84605,79.98475));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84605,79.98475));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84593,79.98412));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84591,79.98405));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84587,79.98385));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84582,79.98344));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84573,79.98293));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.84575,79.98292));
    path.add(new LatLng(6.8469,79.98272));
```

Comment: I'm drawing this once

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. It works after removing the duplication.